# How to improve fit of non-linear curve fitting with python

Tags: python-2.7, curve-fitting, nonlinear-optimization, non-linear-regression

I have tried using scipy.optimize curve fit and I have used polyfit. Polyfit actually worked better but the result is still quite atrocious. We were to import data via a .txt file, which is where the loc, q, and z values are coming from. Any guidance is appreciated!

My plot at this time using polyfit

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1IlGX.png

Here is my code so far:

```
def func2(q, A2, sigma2, d):    
    b1 = np.zeros(q.size)
    b2 = np.zeros(q.size)

    for i in xrange(q.size):

        if (np.absolute(q[i])<= 0.5): 

            b1[i] = np.cos((np.pi*0.5)*(q[i]-0.5))**2
        else:
            b1[i] = 1

    for i in xrange(q.size):

        if (np.absolute(q[i])<= 0.5):
            b2[i] = np.cos((np.pi*0.5)*(q[i]+0.5))**2
        else:
            b2[i] = 0    
    return A2*b1*np.exp((-(q-0.5)**2)/(2*sigma2**2))+A2*b2*np.exp((-(q+0.5)**2)/(2*sigma2**2))+d

loc = down_loc['loc'];
q = vel_var['q'];
z1 = vel_var['z_1'];
z2 = vel_var['z_2'];
z3 = vel_var['z_3'];
z4 = vel_var['z_4'];
z5 = vel_var['z_5'];
z6 = vel_var['z_6'];
z7 = vel_var['z_7'];
z8 = vel_var['z_8'];
z9 = vel_var['z_9'];
z10 = vel_var['z_10'];
z11 = vel_var['z_11'];



sig2 = np.zeros(11)
variance2 = np.zeros((11,3))

popt, pcov = curve_fit(func2, q, z1,p0=(1,2,3),method='lm')
sig2[0]=popt[1]
variance2[0,:] = np.diag(pcov)

popt, pcov = curve_fit(func2, q, z2)
sig2[1]=popt[1]
variance2[1,:] = np.diag(pcov)

#popt, pcov = curve_fit(func2, q, z3)
sig2[2]=popt[1]
variance2[2,:] = np.diag(pcov)

popt, pcov = curve_fit(func2, q, z4)
sig2[3]=popt[1]
variance2[3,:] = np.diag(pcov)

popt, pcov = curve_fit(func2, q, z5)
sig2[4]=popt[1]
variance2[4,:] = np.diag(pcov)

popt, pcov = curve_fit(func2, q, z6)
sig2[5]=popt[1]
variance2[5,:] = np.diag(pcov)

popt, pcov = curve_fit(func2, q, z7)
sig2[6]=popt[1]
variance2[6,:] = np.diag(pcov)

popt, pcov = curve_fit(func2, q, z8)
sig2[7]=popt[1]
variance2[7,:] = np.diag(pcov)

popt, pcov = curve_fit(func2, q, z9)
sig2[8]=popt[1]
variance2[8,:] = np.diag(pcov)

popt, pcov = curve_fit(func2, q, z10)
sig2[9]=popt[1]
variance2[9,:] = np.diag(pcov)

popt, pcov = curve_fit(func2, q, z11)
sig2[10]=popt[1]
variance2[10,:] = np.diag(pcov)


popt, pcov = curve_fit(func2, q, z2)


fit = np.poly1d(np.polyfit(q, z2, 20))

plt.plot(q, z2, '.', label='Data')
plt.plot(q, fit(q), label='Fit')
plt.xlabel('Transverse Direction Coordinates (z/D)')
plt.ylabel('Velocity Variance (Column 2)')
plt.legend()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. I would recommend two ways of improving your question:
1. It is not entirely clear, why you think that "the result is still quite atrocious." Could you explain more precisely what is wrong with it?
2. Without your .txt file it is difficult for us to re-try your program. Would it be possible to share the inputs as well? Or yet better, to make the example as small as possible first?

Comment: Thank you. I think at this time I am unable to upload a file to a post as a new member? The data is quite large (12 columns with 230 rows) which is why I didn't want to include it. But if you look at the link to my data plot the curve does not seem to fit the data very well. I am thinking this may be because there are so man outliers and I am unsure how to give them less weight to make the curve fit more appropriately if that makes sense?